# Yes or No While Loops c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that allows the user to input an integer, which I then reverse and output back to them. I would like the program to run again at the user's request and allow them to enter another integer, but I'm unable to do so.

Here is what I expect my program to be able to do:

> Enter a positive integer: 38475
>   This integer in reverse is 57483.
>   Would you like to do this again? (y/n) y
>   Enter a positive integer: 9584
>   This integer in reverse is 4859.
>   Would you like to do this again? (y/n) n

And here is my code, which currently handles reversing the input.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, i = 10;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << " This integer in reverse is ";

    do
    {
        cout << (num%i) / (i / 10);
        i *= 10;
    } while ((num * 10) / i != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I have my program run multiple times based on user input?

Comment: homework? :-) just put all this in another do..while (or while) loop asking for continue, do while answer is "y"

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a char to 'y'. Obtain the user input and set that to the char after the user provides the input. The while loop should look something like `while (answer == 'y')`. This way it'll run at least once.

Answer (score 1):

[As Ceelos points out in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32772008/4143855) you can do this with another `do while` loop using a single `char` and ask the user whether they wish to repeat the program or not. I have added an example for clarity:

```
int main()
{
    char repeat = 'n';
    do
    {
        int num, i = 10;
        cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
        cin >> num;
        cout << " This integer in reverse is ";

        do
        {
            cout << (num%i) / (i / 10);
            i *= 10;
        } while ((num * 10) / i != 0);

        // Ask the user if they wish to play again
        cout << endl << "Would you like to have another turn?" << endl;
        // Get their answer
        cin >> repeat;

    } while (repeat == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me complete it.